# Terminal based file browser, à la mocp

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal

I'm looking for a file browser from the terminal. Ideally, a program that looks and feels like mocp (music on console player) dedicated to file browsing. Repeatedly typing in 'cd' and 'ls' in the terminal is too irksome. Also, I'm sick of aliasing commands to cd to specific highly-used folders in my filesystem.

Recommendations? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My terminal is bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you'll find [midnight commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/) very useful.
In ubuntu you should be able to install it with:

```
apt-get install mc
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many console-based file manager, mc as Luis said above, and [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/), [vifm](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/), [lfm](http://www.terra.es/personal7/inigoserna/lfm/), and many-many other.